# Different versions of TLS in record layer and handshake layer

Tags: tls, openssl, protocols

There is application that uses OpenSSL 1.0.2g. Application is able to receive incoming connections and initiate outbound connection. Application sends ClientHello message during create outbound connection. In this time I see that versions of TLS are different in record layer and handshake layer.

[image]

The following flags are used to set in global context.

```
SSL_CTX_set_options(ssl_list[i].ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION | SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE| SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1);
```

This behavior is expected according to RFC. But for me it's not clear why in another traces I see the same TLS versions in record layer and handshake layer.

```
Secure Sockets Layer
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 122
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 101
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
```

Thanks!

Comment: TLS version negotiation?  The question seems good, the only point is that I do not really see a question in there.  Are you asking why does it happen?  If the RFC allows it and there is no clear security problem in doing it that way the developer may do it whichever way he wants.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'd like to know is there any programmatic way to change that?